# Format checkbox array to csv

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes with `name=ap[]` and want to use jquery to convert the checked checkbox values into comma separated values so i can then parse as a query string. How would i go about this? `.serialize()` makes the string over complicated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[jQuery.fn.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) itterates over a jQuery set, and returns a new array (inside a jQuery wrapper) which contains nodes equal to the return value of each itterarion. You can then get that array by calling [jQuery.fn.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/), then use that array for anything you want:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
  return $(this).val(); // value will be in the returned array
})
.get() // extract the new array from the jQuery object
.join(','); //do anything you want with the array
```

In your case this can be applied as such:

```
var list = $(':checkbox[name="ap[]"]:checked').map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');

alert(list);
```

Comment: thanks @avaq I looked at .map but didn't quite understand it fully. so how would i access/alert the csv? `alert($(:checkbox:checked).get());` ??

Comment: I'll edit my answer to answer your question more specificly, one moment.

Comment: also is this more efficient than using .each or just preferred as it is less code?

Comment: It does the same as each(), as in; it itterates over a jQuery element set. The difference is that each() is meant for any itteration logic and map() is meant for stuff like your question. I don't know about the performance but I'm guessing it won't make much of a difference. It has the advantage of not having to do an if() check on every itteration, but the performance impact that jQuery adds by wrapping the returned array in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = '';
$("[name=ap[]]").is("checked").each(function(){
   list += $(this).val() + ',';
});
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, but needs a fence-post fix imo, this will leave a trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

```
var csv="";
$('input:checkbox[name="ap[]"]:checked').each(function(index) { 

if(csv !="" ) csv+=",";

csv+=$(this).val();

});
```

Comment: Great thank you :)Just for future reference what do you put the 'index' in there for?

Comment: It's the index of the element 0 the first one , two the third one , lets say you need to do something with the third element , you can achieve that using its index